# Leave the US permanently 60 days then fly back to Mexico for a month before reenter US, is it possible?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

My last visit to the US was on Dec 17-2014 until Mar 14-2015 under the ESTA/VWP. I flew home in the Netherland after that. I plan to fly to Mexico on 15 May and want to stay there for a month, then get back to the US by motorcycle on 15 June. Would it be alright with the 90 days rule ?